# Why isn't Flink distributing my work evenly and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job that reads from a data source that has 5 partitions. I have my parallelism in the config file set to 100 for each task manager.

In my input operation, it only uses 5/100 task managers to read the 5 partitions. But after that, in my map and filter operations, I want Flink to take the data it read in previously and distribute it to each of the 100 task managers. But it isn't doing that. It only sends the data to 5/100 task managers in the map and filter operations. The remaining 95/100 are not used at all.

How do I force flink to use all the task managers?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things factor into this:

(1) The effective parallelism of Flink's KafkaSource is limited by the number of Kafka partitions.

(2) Flink defaults to using operator chaining wherever possible -- meaning that in all 100 instances the map and filter are running in the same thread as the source. This avoids the overhead of serializing and deserializing the events, and sending them over the network. However, only 5 of those source instances are consuming any data, so only 5 chains are doing any work.

By far the best way to put the other 95 task managers to work would be to increase the number of Kafka partitions to 100. Failing that, you could explicitly set the parallelism of the Kafka source operator to 5, and the parallelism of the map and filter to 100. That will force a round-robin rebalancing between the source and the map/filter operations. Given the overhead involved, that may or may not perform any better.